# ActiveMQ 5.15 with JMS 2.0

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis, jms2

Can ActiveMQ 5.15 work with JMS 2.0, per official documentation it uses JMS 1.1. What are the implications of using ActiveMQ 5.15 with JMS 2.0. If ActiveMQ 5.15 + JMS 2.0 is not a way to go then is Artemis a good alternative and is Artemis stable enough to be used in production-grade enterprise applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ 5.x does not support JMS 2 so you can't use them together.

ActiveMQ Artemis does support JMS 2. It is designed to replace ActiveMQ 5.x so it's a good alternative.

It is certainly stable enough to use in production grade enterprise applications and many users have been doing so for many years now. To be clear, the core of ActiveMQ Artemis based on HornetQ which was the JMS implementation shipped with the latest JBoss Application Server, Wildfly Application Server, and Red Hat's JBoss Enterprise Application Server as well as Red Hat's AMQ 7 messaging product.

Comment: Thanks much for the detailed response, appreciate your help. One question, I read JMS 2.0 is backward-compatible with JMS 1.1 so shouldn't ActiveMq 5.x + JMS 2.0 just work? Sorry to bother again, I should have asked this before.

Comment: JMS 2 *is* backwards compatible with JMS 1.1. However, that only means that a client using the JMS 1.1 API can use the JMS 2 API jars. It doesn't means a client using the JMS 2 API can use a JMS 1.1 implementation. That's just not how it works.

Comment: This totally makes sense, sorry for asking this silly question. Thank you for your help, appreciate that.